# Configurable Stateful Traffic Generator Advice

Tags: traffic, load-testing, network-traffic, test, automated-testing

I need a traffic generator tool which I should be able to configure followings;

- Number of Packets
- Number of Sessions
- Number of TCP, UDP packets
- Average number of packets in a session
- Average packet size
- Standard deviation of packet sizes
- Average of packet interval times
- Standard deviation of packet interval time
- Average connection duration of TCP flows
- Generated packets per second

Is there a tool where I can configure all of these? If not, where should I begin, I think scapy can not handle high speeds.(I need very high numbers) Should I start writing it in C, C++?

Also packet per second

Comment: Suggest to have a look at Apache Jmeter, which is a very powerful tool for loadtesting. It has a TCP sampler available & should cover most of your needs. https://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks for the advice @hargut, I checked it out a little bit but couldn't see the things I can configure or not, can you point out which sections will cover my needs? Where should I focus?

Comment: Jmeter is modular built and therefore very versatile. Modules to meet dome of your requirements can be: TCP Sampler, UDP Sampler, Thread Group, ... All of the jmeter framework can be used as well programatically using a Java (compliant) language.